# Conflicting dependencies in same gem. Bundler could not find compatible version for gem "faraday"

Tags: rubygems, dependencies, bundler, google-api-client

So I am running bundle install, and I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    google-api-client (= 0.5.0) ruby depends on
      faraday (~> 0.8.1) ruby

    google-api-client (= 0.5.0) ruby depends on
      faraday (0.9.0.rc5)
```

The way I see this is that one of my gems, the `google-api-client -v 0.5.0` has internal conflicting dependencies. How is this possible?

I have tried deleting the `Gemfile.lock`, I have tried different versions (0.5.0 and 0.6.0) of the `google-api-client` but nothing seems to help. Anyone knows what is going on here?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://code.stripe.com'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'omniauth', '1.1.1'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin', '0.0.8'
gem 'omniauth-angellist', git: 'git://github.com/codequest-eu/omniauth-angellist.git', ref: 'b970a2bc834b35980b0a81162e0d367df880a69b'
gem 'angellist_api', '1.0.2'
gem 'linkedin', '0.3.7'
gem 'system-bang', '1.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.3'
gem 'unicorn', '4.3.1'
gem 'pdfkit', '0.5.2'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '0.9.9.1'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.3.3'
gem 'kaminari', '0.14.1'
gem 'uuidtools', '2.1.2'
gem 'google-api-client', '0.5.0'
gem 'paperclip', '3.3.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '1.7.1'
gem 'stripe', '1.8.3'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
  gem 'compass-rails', '1.0.3'
  gem 'oily_png', '1.0.2'
  gem 'backbone-on-rails', '0.9.2.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'thin', '1.5.0'
  gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '0.6.1'
  gem 'rails_best_practices', '1.13.3'
  gem 'quiet_assets', '1.0.1'
  gem 'bullet', '4.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'spork-rails', '3.2.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'email_spec', '1.4.0'
  gem 'rspec-html-matchers', '0.3.5'
  gem 'assert_difference', '0.5.0'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.5.4'

  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '0.13.0'
  gem 'headless', '0.3.1'
  gem 'fakeweb', '1.3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'ci_reporter', '1.7.0'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.6.4', require: false
  gem 'simplecov-rcov', '0.2.3', require: false
  gem 'ruby-prof', '0.11.2', require: false
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', require: 'v8'

  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.9.1'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this issue was only present in version `google-api-client -v 0.5.0` and `google-api-client -v 0.6.0` (possibly others). Changing to 0.6.4 solved the issue for me.

Hopefully this will help someone else out there.

Comment: I had a similar issue but using version 0.6.4 does not help, I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689397/ruby-on-rails-gem-dependency-conflict-when-install-google-api-client ; Before using version 0.6.4; I also had tried with version 0.6.3 and having a loop depency between gem launchy and gem faraday. When I run 'bundle update faraday' it complains 'lanchy'; when I run 'bundle update launchy' it complains 'faraday'.