# Ruby On Rails gem dependency conflict when install "google-api-client"

Tags: google-api-client

I added to Gemfile : gem 'google-api-client', "0.6.4"

1> execute “bundle install”, and got this error:
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "addressable":
  In Gemfile:
    google-api-client (= 0.6.4) ruby depends on
      addressable (>= 2.3.2) ruby

```
koala (>= 0) ruby depends on
  addressable (2.2.8)
```

2> execute “bundle update koala”, got this error:
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "launchy":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    launchy (2.1.0)

In Gemfile:
    google-api-client (= 0.6.4) ruby depends on
      launchy (>= 2.1.1) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

What is the core issue of this error?
And how can I solve it?

Thank you.

[Update]
When I execute 'bundle update addressable', got this error:
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "launchy":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    launchy (2.1.0)

In Gemfile:
    google-api-client (= 0.6.4) ruby depends on
      launchy (>= 2.1.1) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The version of koala you are using required addressable-2.2.8, but google-api-client wants addressable-2.3.2 or higher. The latest version of koala does not specify a specific version of addressable, so try updating koala:

```
bundle update koala
```

Comment: Hi infused, I had mentioned within my question the error displayed when I executed "bundle update koala"

Comment: Yes, indeed I tried "bundle update" in the first place. It did not work.